# Switch entry type depending on entry field

Tags: entry-form

Is there a way to switch entry type dynamically depending on the selection of a field value on a entry page? For instance, could I have a structure for motorized transportation and then have a dropdown that has the values car and motorcycle. If "car" is selected then an entry page would be presented that gets number of doors, if "motorcycle" is select then an entry page is selected that gets engine cc's?

Comment: What should be the difference to the existing entry type switcher in the cp?

Comment: Are you referring to group entry type? I am new to Craft so perhaps the capability exists I just haven't found it?

Comment: Yes that's the case. There is a little dropdown in the details section (at the right site) where you can change the entry type. What do you mean with "group entry type" there is no such a thing in Craft